# .htaccess password protection breaks WP/Twitter feeds

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, twitter, .htpasswd

Working on a site for a client who has a dev.sitename.com subdomain for development, which I just went in and password protected with .htaccess/.htpasswd files. Now, all the Wordpress and Twitter feeds are broken and giving "authentication failed" (wordpress) and "invalid username/password" (twitter) errors. I've Googled around for the last hour, but it's one of those combinations of search terms that get you tons of results that aren't relevant (mostly WP security). Has anyone ever run into this and could point me in the right direction, as I've never had to deal with these things behind .htaccess protected directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third question in a row I've eventually posted my own answer to. Oh well, I hope they help someone else. Maybe people thought this question was stupid, who knows, but I just dropped the following into the Wordpress folder's .htaccess file:

```
Allow From All
Satisfy Any
```

The kicker that was tripping me up was using Satisfy Any instead of just Allow From All so that both the rule from the parent directory and the rule in this file are both evaluated as the parent folder's rule will override this one otherwise. Silly.